How to get rid of this warning: The 'x' parameter is captured in the state of the enclosing type and its value is also passed to the base constructor
This warning appears in this declaration:
public class PersonaService(SecuWebModulesPersonalContext db,
    IHttpContextAccessor accessor,
    IGuidGenerator guidGenerator,
    IHookBroadcasting hookBroadcasting) : CommonBaseService(accessor)

With that, this warning appears:

The 'x' parameter is captured in the state of the enclosing type and
its value is also passed to the base constructor. The base class can
also capture the value.

I know this warning is originated because I am injecting IHttpContextAccessor to the PersonaService class because I am using it in it.
On the other hand, I need to pass that variable to the base class because the constructor requires it, whose definition is this:
public class CommonBaseService
{
    public CommonBaseService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }
}

I am using that IHttpContextAccessor inside the base class also.
How can I declare those classes and pass that dependency injection parameter correctly?
Thanks
Jaime

I'm not sure how you're getting that warning. Could you [edit] your post with a [mre]? I've tried to make one based on your description but I haven't seen a warning yet https://dotnetfiddle.net/1kKJiM

Never mind... I have found the solution here after I posted the question: https://www.benday.com/2024/07/18/how-to-fix-c-primary-constructor-warning-cs9107-parameter-is-captured-into-the-state-of-the-enclosing-type/. Thanks anyway

This question is similar to: How to "properly" (idiomatic) avoid CS9107 when passing primary constructor parameters to base. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The warning is that your PersonaService class is using accessor so it has to capture its own copy of it in addition to passnig it to the base class. If the base class makes that availalble as a property, use that instead. It looks like you might have control over the base class, so you should make a protected property to expose it to derived classes.

@madreflection Thanks! that was what I finally did. The warning went away.
